# Add string into string array using for statement

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, file

I have a problem trying to add strings to an array and then writing to a file, with this code I can write the file but it saves 1 file per string and I need to save it as a list how can I fix this problem to only create 1 file for all the strings during the for statement. Thanks in advance

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            final Request request = new Request(Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                    edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                    Common.currentUser.getName(),
                    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                    "0",
                    edtComment.getText().toString(),
                    cart);


            requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setValue(request);
            String[]resultado=new String[cart.size()];
            for ( i=0;i<cart.size();i++) {

                String codebar = cart.get(i).getCodebar();
                String quantity = cart.get(i).getQuantity();


//THIS LINE BELOW IS THE ONE I NEED TO HAVE IN TXT FILE
                String nuevo =format+", "+convertCodeToMonth(month)+", "+request.getPhone()+", "+"01"+", "+"2"+", "+"3"+", "+codebar+","+quantity;
//THIS LINE BELOW SUPPOSED TO RECEIVE THE STRINGS
                resultado[i]=nuevo;
//THIS LINE BELOW SUPPOSED TO WRITE TO FILE
                writeToFile(resultado[i]);
                Log.d("INFOOOOOOOOOOO", "onClick: "+resultado[i]);
            }
            new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Gracias por su compra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();


        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();

}

private void writeToFile(String s) {
    final File archivo = new File(filePaths.FILES,format+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".txt");
    Log.d("WRITING", "writeToFile: "+filePaths.FILES);
    try {
        archivo.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(s);

        myOutWriter.close();

        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Exception", "writeToFile: "+e.toString() );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use StringBuilder instead of an array? This would allow you to build 1 single String object ready to save into your file…

```
StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
for ( i=0;i<cart.size();i++) {
    String codebar = cart.get(i).getCodebar();
    String quantity = cart.get(i).getQuantity();
    //THIS LINE BELOW IS THE ONE I NEED TO HAVE IN TXT FILE
    String nuevo =format+", "+convertCodeToMonth(month)+", "+request.getPhone()+", "+"01"+", "+"2"+", "+"3"+", "+codebar+","+quantity;
    //append the new data, and a line break :
    resultado.append(nuevo);
    resultado.append("\n");
    Log.d("INFOOOOOOOOOOO", "onClick: "+nuevo);
}
writeToFile(resultado.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this was the perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to create this file outside of your writeToFile method! Then you can reference it inside of the method, and it won't create a new one every time.